# Drinking Martini? Here is to me!

Tags: riddle, knowledge, rhyme

The expected answer is a rhyme also!

> I'm there when it's cloudy
>
> I'm there when it's sunny
>
> And when I ask questions
>
> I am right on the money
>
> I take both sides
>
> In any conversation
>
> I am not so common
>
> Yet very very common

Don't be __ __

I am ___ __

Comment: Does the underscores mean letters in the answer? (So the answer is two two-letter words, and (next line) a three-letter word and a two-letter word?)

Comment: No. Two words on each line. Once you get the answer you can rhyme that easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wonder whether you are:

> **The letter 'Y'**

*I'm there when it's cloudy*
*I'm there when it's sunny*

> The letter 'Y' appears at the end of both CLOUD**Y** and SUNN**Y**.

*And when I ask questions*

> When spoken out loud, 'Y' is a homophone of 'WHY?' (a question)

*I am right on the money*

> The symbol for the Japanese yen (¥) resembles a Y with two horizontal bars. Plus, as @JMP points out in comments, 'Y' is literally the letter on the RIGHT-hand side of the word MONE**Y**.

*I take both sides*
*In any conversation*

> To each party in a conversation the other is '**Y**OU', which begins with 'Y'.
>  <sub>(As pointed out later by the OP, 'I take both sides' further refers to this letter's ability to be both a vowel and a consonant.)</sub>

*I am not so common*

> The letter 'Y' is not one of the most frequently used in the English language.
>  <sub>(Another interpretation pointed out later by the OP concerns the element Yttrium - whose Periodic Table symbol is 'Y' - being one of the "*rare*-earth elements".)</sub>

*Yet very very common*

> Approximately half of the world's population carry a Y-chromosome (males), which makes it very widespread indeed... This line also contains 3 Y's (***Y***et ver**y** ver**y** common) as if for emphasis.

As for the title:

> A martini is typically served in a Y-shaped glass! (Thanks @JMP)

And to answer in rhyme:

> Don't be **so shy**
>  I am **letter Y**!

Comment: AND... check out https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=martini+glass&qpvt=martini+glass&FORM=IGRE

Comment: @JMP OH, OF COURSE! How did I miss that?! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm there when it's cloudy

I'm there when it's sunny

> When it's cloudy common sense tells us to carry an umbrella, and when it's sunny to put on a sun screen

And when I ask questions

I am right on the money

> Questions asked with common sense are accurate

I take both sides

In any conversation

> Common sense guides us to consider both sides of a conversation before jumping to conclusions

I am not so common

Yet very very common

> Common sense is not so common is a phrase from voltaire, however as the name "common" in common sense suggests it is very common

From this line of reasoning

> Don't be non sense
>  I am common sense

I might be way off but that's my attempt